# Shared 'confirmation link' for newsletters allows anyone to subscribe the user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, newsletter

Bart De Vos shared a link to the SE newsletter page:

https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/54685/1129940053?code=555e60701591569ee92f9fb88c9a2cf49bdf25c9237d0da88ea7aff8145a72ce&confirmed=serverfault.com&day=tuesday

Oops! He shared his confirmation link.

I got the message: "Thank you for signing up for the Stack Overflow Newsletter! You will receive the newsletter every Tuesday." which is a little confusing as it subscribed him, not me.

I then proceeded to sign him up for the Christianity and German Language Newsletters by clicking the 'Subscribe' button after opening up the link in a private browsing window.

HAX!

[image: Good LOLs]

Comment: Don't worry, I just signed him up for the rest of them.

Comment: Loving the LEGO® Answers Newsletter by the way, Thanks! :-)

Comment: For shame! [FixItFixItFixIt!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6PZhONZ3Ac)

Comment: There are 78 Stack Exchange sites. I predict that Bart will have a lot of email to read shortly...

Comment: Also, you can edit the day (`&day=dayofweek`), why is that? Does it mean I'll be getting my Japanese Language and Usage Newsletter on monday now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design: *manage-your-newsletters* links are like *manage-your-craigslist-post* links – they shouldn't be shared.

(We have, however, disabled the particular link shared in this question, to prevent further any further unwanted changes to Bart De Vos's subscriptions.)

Comment: He'll probably be happy to hear that :)

Comment: Thanks :-) Let the unsubscribing begin.

Answer (score 15):

[image: How I feel now]

Comment: I hate you for making me upvote this